# Working with transfinite ordinals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, calculator

I'm attempting to program a transfinite ordinal calculator in JavaScript. In other words, find a way to process [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) in js.

I'm planning on using ES6's classes, with some form of constructor, and methods for processing comparisons of terms and operations such as addition or multiplication over the set of ordinals. The problem is that I don't know where to start. I need firstly a way to store ordinals in an instance of an Ordinal class, and a way of comparing to Ordinals. After that point everything should be smooth sailing.

If anyone could provide any insight into how I might approach this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz I eventually managed to figure out a way of doing it; given the question is 6 months old I wonder why it was bountied. I guess I could answer my own question if you're interested in how I did it.

Comment: i am interested, if you add not only what you have as a possible solution but if you add an frame of the wanted form of try to tackle the problem.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm not sure what you mean by "frame of the wanted form of try to tackle the problem".

Comment: with frame, i mean how do you use omega or aleph as symbolic constants for some calculations.

Comment: @L.McDonald I put a bounty on the question because I thought it was a good one & it didn't have an answer. If you post your solution I'd be happy to award the bounty to you (:

Comment: I'll answer with a few possible solutions, and quickly throw together some of them and attach them when I'm done.

Comment: There is http://www.transfinite.ch/ (documentation and links to source at http://www.transfinite.ch/doc/index.html).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I was aware of this at the time, I guess I was looking for something more robust and extendable than that. A much more valuable resource was 'OrdCalc' which is currently only available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/ord/ it seems. It has quite extensive documentation and was invaluable in making the library I did eventually end up making, as seen in my comment on my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the last 6 months I've found several methods of storing ordinals, these include:

- Cantor Normal Form as an array
- Extended Cantor Normal Form as nested arrays of pairs
- An ordinal notation (known as TAN) developed by a member of the Googology community
- Veblen's Hierarchy of Fixed Points
- An ordinal collapsing function

Disclaimer: I use a common convention when writing out ordinals. I use w to represent omega, the least transfinite ordinal; e to represent the epsilon numbers (fixed points of a -> w^a) or the function enumerating them; similarly, in the case of Veblen's Hierarchy I'll use phi to denote such for ordinal collapsing functions I'll use psi. When explaining how operations work I'll use `this` to denote the first operand and `other` to denote the second.

Cantor Normal Form expresses ordinals as the sum of terms in the form w^b * a and therefore has a limit of w^w, intuitively it can be expressed as an array, where the i'th element of the term represents the a in the term w^i * a, e.g. the array `[4, 5, 6]` represents the ordinal w^2*6 + w*5 + 4. Adding is simple enough. Based on the principle that 1 + w = w, w + w^2 = w^2 and so on, we can fill the array with 0s up to the `other.length - 1`'th element and then add the elements in `other` to their corresponding elements in `this`. Multiplication is more tricky. If `other` contains multiple non-zero elements, we can use the distributive law (which doesn't apply the other way) and return the sum of `this` multiplied by each of `other`'s terms. Otherwise, if `this` has multiple non-zero elements, if `other` is finite (`other.length == 1`) then multiply the most significant term of `this` by `other` and return `other`. In the final case ignore all but the most significant term of `this` and multiply by `other`. And if both operands have only one term then shift a bunch of 0s into `this` (specifically `other.length - 1`) and return `this`. Exponentiation is trivial then as `other` must be finite otherwise the result would surpass the range of this method, and can just be done by iterating multiplication, because I'm lazy and can do better later.

Extended Cantor Normal Form is similar, though the exponents for each term can also be ordinals, which complicates things, though extends the limit of this to e0 (the least fixed point of a -> w^a. We can store ordinals as an array of pairs. The first element of the pair can be coefficient of the terms and the second element is the exponent, represented by another array of pairs. The first thing that needs to be addressed in this form would be normalization. Firstly you'd need to remove all terms which are 0, then iterate through the array and keep track of the largest exponent, if you encounter an element with a lower exponent that the current highest you'd splice it out of the array. Once this is done you check for terms with the same exponent and add the coefficient of the other to one, removing the other. The array will then be normalized (there's probably a more efficient way to do this, leave a comment). Addition follows then become trivial. Simply concatenate the arrays of `other` and `this` and normalize. Multiplication is similar to before. If `other.length > 1` then we can use the distributive law (which doesn't apply the other way) and return the sum of `this` multiplied by each of `other`'s terms. Otherwise, if `this` has multiple terms, if `other` is finite then multiply the most significant term of `this` by `other` and return `other`. In the final case ignore all but the most significant term of `this` and multiply by `other`. Then simply add the exponent of `other`'s only term to `this`'s only term and return `this`. Exponentiation is no longer trivial, but isn't difficult. Firstly, remove all but the most significant term from `this`, then multiply the exponent by `other`. Done.

A member of the Googology* community, TGR, created TAN as an extremely powerful array notation for generating large numbers, though it was essentially the fast growing hierarchy with an array-like ordinal notation. The ordinal notation isn't exactly well defined, though it can be understood well enough. [TAN](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cre9oNyKukphx0o-h6x8aaIN0UmDoCGtTNKxss4d1mI/edit?usp=sharing). Note that I would only code the arrays without 'separators' for simplicity. Ordinals can be stored as arrays where elements are either arrays or integers. Normalization can be done by popping 0s off the end of the array and checking if any elements have greater value than the outer array (without that element), if they are, then remove the outer array. This is as each of the elements of the arrays enumerates as a function of the form a + b, a * w^b, e, phi_2, phi_3 etc, and such an array just as [0, 0, [0, 0, 0, 1]] would be e(psi_2(0)) which is simply equal to phi_2(0) as phi_2(0) is a fixed point of the function enumerating the epsilon numbers. Adding in this notation is simple, take the first element of the `this`, and then the first element of that, and so on until we get to an integer, then if `other` is finite simply add it on, if `other` is transfinite then replace the integer in `this`. Multiplying is similar, though you instead increase the second term. Again applying the distributive law when necessary, and making sure that it is recognized that increasing the second element by a is the same as multiplying by w^a. As mentioned above, exponentiating is the same as multiplying the exponent and then removing the added part. This was my favourite method of storing ordinals because it's rather unique and interesting, and has a high limit which is easy to achieve.

The other two notations are likely possible, and I've had ideas for how to do so. Veblen Hierarchy could be stored similarly to TAN though storing an array of terms like CNF and ECNF, and each term is an array in Veblen Style, though each element must also be an array of terms to allow the ability to store all ordinals. Ordinal collapsing functions would be more difficult, I propose storing the symbolic string as an abstract syntax tree, the primary issue would be normalization as that could get out of control very easily,

*the study and nomenclature of large finite numbers, though as fast growing and other ordinal hierarchies play an important role in such, there is a large variety of ordinal notation developed, though most would be incredibly difficult to program.

Comment: Nice answer! Do you have any code online? I am most curious to further explore the fixed points method; unfortunately I am not a very proficient coder..

Comment: Also, I would like to be able to learn more about your proposal of using abstract syntax trees if possible.

Comment: @meowzz I firstly made the one in TAN because it seemed the most fun, though the code is spaghetti and doesn't work in many cases; though the code is online: https://github.com/Reinhardt-C/VebleNum.js

Comment: I'm planning on making the ordinal collapsing function one at some point, though I'll need to come up with a method of normalization, and I'd be happy to share with you any ideas I come up with.